# How to simplify a Circuitikz diagram with many names?

Tags: circuitikz

I wanted to learn circuitikz, so I redraw the following two-transistor oscillator:

[image]

The document I came up with is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        coordinate (orig) at (0, 0);
        
        \draw (0, 0) 
            to[led] ++(0, -2)
            to[R, l_=$R_1$] ++(0, -2) coordinate(r1b)
            to[C, l^=$C_1$] ++(2, 0) coordinate(r2b)
            to[R, l_=$R_2$] ++(0, 2) 
            to[short] ++(0, 2) coordinate(p1)
            to[short] ++(-2, 0);

        \draw (6, 0) 
            to[led] ++(0, -2)
            to[R, l^=$R_4$] ++(0, -2) coordinate(r4b)
            to[C, l_=$C_2$] ++(-2, 0) coordinate(r3b)
            to[R, l^=$R_3$] ++(0, 2) 
            to[short] ++(0, 2) coordinate(p2)
            to[short] ++(2, 0);

        \draw (p1) to[short, *-*] (p2);
        
        \draw (r1b) to[short] ++(0, -1) coordinate (q1c); 
        \draw (q1c) node[npn, anchor=C, xscale=-1] (q1) {\scalebox{-1}[1]{Q1}};
        \draw (q1.E) to[short] ++(0, -1) coordinate(q1e);

        \draw (r4b) to[short] ++(0, -1) coordinate (q2c); 
        \draw (q2c) node[npn, anchor=C] (q2) {Q2};
        \draw (q2.E) to[short] ++(0, -1) coordinate(q2e);

        \draw (q1e) to[short] (q2e);

        \draw (r3b) to[short] (r2b |- q1.B) to[short] (q1.B);
        \draw (r2b) to[short] (r3b |- q2.B) to[short] (q2.B);

    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{My first circuit.}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which generates the following:

[image]

I'm happy with the result, but realized I had to define an awful lot of coordinates to make it work properly. For example, for the transistors, because I wanted to extend the collector and emitter leads, I had to redefine their names instead of using the built-in ones.

Is there a better way to build this diagram to result in less code required without sacrificing readability?

Comment: It seems quite ok to me (although I would scale down diodes and transistors up... Try with `romano` style :-))

Comment: @Rmano Thanks! I think I found something interesting, "transistor paths", which helps. However, it's strange that a transistor path starts with the emitter and not the collector, especially since the mental mode for circuits tends to be +ve to -ve, top to bottom. I'm going to post a separate question about this.

Comment: You can name components using the `to[R, n=R1]` option.  (Not to be confused with the label.)